# aws appsync turning off real-time synchronization

Tags: aws-appsync

AppSync synchronizes with the cloud when the device reconnects.  What if I don't want to synchronize when the device reconnects.

What is a method for manually controlling when AppSync synchronizes when there is a cloud connection?

Comment: I recommend asking this on the appropriate GitHub repo: Android (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android), iOS (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios), or JavaScript (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js)